# Не могу сделать push второго проекта на github

Tags: git, github

Сегодня начал знакомство с gihub. Создал удаленный репозиторий с именем "MY_PROJECT", цель - складывать туда мои ДЗ с курсов. Запушил туда первое ДЗ с именем "HW1", добавил gitignore `"*.Designer.cs"`. Все зашло красиво и выглядит так : `MY_PROJECT/tree/master/HW1/`. Теперь я хочу в этот же репозиторий запушить HW2. Захожу в папку с проектом HW2, запускаю git bash, делаю git init, add, commit,  git remote add origin URL,  git push origin master и получаю ошибку :

```
To https://github.com/MyUserName/MY_PROJECT.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/MyUserName/MY_PROJECT.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Читаю, понимаю, но что хотят вьехать до конца не могу. Если я правильно понял, он хочет что бы я все залили себе с удаленного репозитория и только потом делал push уже с этой новой папкой HW2.
Прошу подсказать пожалуйста как правильно сделать.

Comment: `git init` нужен только для инициализации гита, когда его еще нет. Для коммита и пуша это делать уже не нужно... у тебя на компе папки HW1 и HW2 находятся в одной и той же папке в которой есть папка `.git` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет, в разных. Это разные 2 проекта в студии. Получается в каждой папке своя .git

Comment: @Winteriscoming в этом случае вам нужны два разных репозитория на гитхабе. Либо чтобы оба проекта лежали в одной папке, в которой создан локальный репозиторий (и лежит папка `.git`)

Comment: @NickVolynkin получается по правильному будет 1 ДЗ = 1 репозиторий? Складывать все ДЗ в один репозиторий - это своего рода костыль?

Comment: @Winteriscoming смотря насколько у вас ДЗ связаны. Вообще же учебная задача. В рабочей задаче будет 1 репозиторий = 1 рабочий проект.

Comment: @Winteriscoming накатал ответ, жду уточняющих вопросов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Кратко: 1 локальный ←→ 1 удаленный репозиторий

Когда вы выполнили `git init` – вы создали в этой папке локальный репозиторий.
Каждому локальному репозиторию должен соответствовать свой отдельный репозиторий на GitHub. Из двух локальных в один удаленный пушить нельзя.

Вам нужен один из двух вариантов:

1. Завести на гитхабе ещё один репозиторий для второго задания и пушить туда.
2. Перекинуть файлы второго задания в папку первого, как угодно разместить всё это в этой папке, сделать ещё один коммит и запушить его.

---

## Подробно

Git и GitHub не работают как место, куда можно произвольно складывать файлы — подобно дропбоксу или гугл-драйву. Давайте разберемся как же они работают вместо этого.

Git предназначен для того, чтобы хранить последовательную историю изменений файлов внутри одной папки. По команде `git init` Git создает в папке проекта папку `.git` — это и называется «репозиторий Git».

Каждое изменение сохраняется в «коммит». Коммиты складываются в «историю изменений» — каждый новый имеет ссылку на предыдущий (родительский) и так до самого первого — у него ссылки нет.

Для удобства работы в Git есть ветки. Ветка — это указатель на последний коммит. Через ссылки на родителей за этот коммит можно вытащить целую цепочку — потому это и называется веткой. Когда вы делаете новый коммит, указатель ветки перемещается на него.

Когда вы заводите проект на GitHub, где-то там на сервере создается аналогичный репозиторий Git. Команда `git push` отправляет данные из конкретной ветки локального репозитория в конкретную ветку удаленного. Например:

```
git push origin master
```

отправляет локальную ветку `master` в ветку `origin/master`.

### Обычный `git push`

Предположим, вы уже отправили коммит A, а теперь сделали ещё коммит B и хотите отправить его. Вот как это выглядит до:

```
локальный: A---B

удаленный: A
```

И после:

```
локальный: A---B

удаленный: A---B
```

Для Git в этой ситуации всё однозначно. Пришёл новый коммит B, его предком является A, который нам уже известен. Можно принимать изменения.

### `git push` из другого репозитория

А теперь что происходит у вас во втором репозитории. Вы тоже сделали в нем один коммит, назовем его X. Ситуация такая:

```
локальный: X

удаленный: A
```

Теперь `git push origin master`. Вы пытаетесь отправить ветку с коммитом X в ветку с коммитом A:

```
локальный: X

удаленный: A ? X
```

Коммиты между собой не связаны. Git не может однозначно определить, что вы имеете в виду:

- Хотите дополнить содержимое, чтобы появился новый коммит, в котором будет содержимое из A и X?
- Хотите заменить A на X?
- Ошиблись номером?

Раз ситуация неоднозначная, Git не рискует и отказывается что-либо делать, сообщая вам об ошибке.

Comment: *"Из двух локальных в один удаленный пушить нельзя."* - да ну?

Answer (score 2):

Гит работает не так
В данный момент ты пытаешься перезаписать содержимое репозитория
ПОЛНОСТЬЮ - если это твоя цель то просто `git push -f`

Если тебе нужно чтоб и первый и второй проект должен быть в одном репозитории
то добавь файлы первого во второй и сделай коммит

Comment: Максим, зачем же вы так опрометчиво советуете `git push -f`. Кто-нибудь может прочитать и бездумно воспользоваться этой довольно опасной командой.

Comment: Там слово капсом написано так что на него обратят внимание)

Comment: А в данном случае это 1) не сработает, потому что на гитхабе первая созданная ветка (обычно master) становится защищенной (нельзя `push -f`), и 2) не поможет, потому что у автора другая задача — всё в одном репозитории держать. Или просто всё на гитхабе.

Comment: 1) в мастер можно делать push -f
2) вместо того чтоб негодовать по поводу моего решения предложите свое?

Comment: Можно, если ветка не защищена. На гитхабе мастер по умолчанию защищен, в него нельзя форспушить. Вы попробуйте.

Comment: Проверил

https://www.dropbox.com/s/07wd43qjdcw2xzh/Screen%20Shot%202017-10-26%20at%2012.28.20%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Хм, и правда не защищает по умолчанию, я ошибся — перепутал с GitLab, там такое поведение.

Answer (score 1):

Вам уже не надо, но может другим еще пригодится.

Надо в локальных проектах веткам дать уникальные имена и тогда их можно будет пушить в один удаленный репозиторий.

В вашем случае нужно было превратить это:
hw1 -- master,
hw2 -- master

например, в это:
hw1 -- hw1,
hw2 -- hw2.